# Get current date as string in databricks using scala

Tags: scala, date

I want to get current date in Scala as a `String`. For example, today current date is 5th Jan. I want to store it as a new variable dynamically as below.

```
val currdate : String = “20220105”
```

When I am using `val currdate = Calendar.getInstance.getTime` then am not getting output in desired format as above.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it's done using the contemporary `java.time` library.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val currdate: String = 
  LocalDate.now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"))
```

Older utilities like `Calendar` and `SimpleDate` still work (mostly) but should be avoided.

Comment: as currdate is string, how to subtract. want to get current date -1 , for example from above output get 20220105, but instead want to get 20220104

Comment: 1-That's a new and different question. 2-Don't subtract it from the `String`, subtract if from the `LocalDate`, i.e. `now.minusDays(1)`.

Comment: yes it worked..

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it as String?
For a Spark query you could use `java.sql.Timestamp` directly.

This how you get it:

```scala
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.time.Instant

val now: Timestamp =
  Timestamp.from(Instant.now())
```

If you really want a formatted String:

```scala
val asString =
  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(now)
```

`SimpleDateFormat` is old and not thread-safe but should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but from string or timestamp cant subtract number of days. from above output am getting current date - 20220105 but instead looking for current date -1 something like 20220104